# Submission of UK visa and cancellation

Tags: visas, uk

I have submitted my UK visa application and already paid the fees. However, I found out that I filled the wrong address and now I wish to edit my application. According to the information given by the UK embassy, I can only do it by cancelling the old application. I wish to do that but in case of the cancellation, will I be able to choose the same interview date as the previous one? I am concerned since there are no dates available in the next 2 months and I am afraid that I might not be able to choose the same date and time slot if I cancel my old application.

Comment: What do you mean with "wrong address"? Address for interview? Your postal address? The UK address where you will stay?

Comment: @VT717 Where are you applying? They may accept a minor handwritten change on the application during your interview

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi wrong of my current address..

Comment: @Traveller I am applying from Cambodia.

Answer (score 4):

If you have already submitted the application then, unfortunately, there is nothing you can do other than filling out a new application and submitting it again.

In case of minor mistakes such as a wrong address. You can write a letter explaining what the mistake was and take it along with the other documents on your appointment date.

*If you plan to do the handwritten change in your application form then make sure that you use a blue/black ink pen (No pencil or different colour ink)*